Simple question on the meaning of $y$ in $Y = y$
We have a random variable $Y$, and say that $Y = y$.  Is $y$ any single value? is it one particular value? Can we represent little $y$ with an axis?
I don't understand how $y$ is fixed. it can be any value.
$Y =y$ can't represent a specific value in the random variable $Y$ because $y$ can be anything; $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6... $ so how is it representing a particular value of $Y$?
what's the difference between $Y$ and $y$?

Hi :) ${Y=y}$ means ${\omega\in\Omega :Y(\omega) =y}$, which is a set, precisely it is the preimage of $y$ under the function $Y$. Here, the function $Y\colon \Omega\to \mathbb R$ is a random variable. And $y$ is a single value as you already said. Maybe, to make an example would help.

Hi Jochen, thanks for that. But when saying Y = y, the y here can take any value, so how is that saying 'Y takes a particular value', it is saying 'Y takes any particular value', right?

Let's say we are rolling a die. Here, our sample space is $\Omega={1,2,3,4,5,6}$. Let's also say that in our game, we need to roll a 5 or higher to win, otherwise we lose. I can represent this game with the random variable $Y:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, defined by $Y(1)=\dots=Y(4)=0$ and $Y(5)=Y(6)=1$. Then ${Y=1}$ is the set ${\omega\in\Omega\mid Y(\omega)=1}={5,6}$.

In probability theory we are working with a probability space, that is a triplet $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ consisting of:

$\Omega$ a sample space. This is a set of all possible outcomes of the experiment.
An event space $\mathcal{F}$ (also known as a sigma algebra). This is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ which contains 'outcomes'. For example, when rolling a die we could look at the outcome 'The die lands on an even number' as the subset $A= \{2,4,6\} \subset \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} = \Omega$.
$\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure. This is a function from $\mathcal{F}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that assigns a value between $0$ and $1$ to every element of $\mathcal{F}$ which we call the probability of the event $A$.

These all satisfy some axioms.
Now, given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ we define a random variable as a function $Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $Y^{-1}(-\infty,x] = \{\omega \in \Omega \: : \: X(\omega) \leq x\} \in \mathcal{F}$.
So, given a random variable $Y$ on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ we can do an 'experiment'. This will result in some result $\omega \in \Omega$. The random variable $Y:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ will then have a corresponding outcome $Y(\omega) \in \mathbb{R}$.
Now, saying that $Y=y$ is notation that is used frequently, but it is sort of sloppy. What we mean by this notation is the following:
$$
Y = y \iff \{\omega \in \Omega \: : \: Y(\omega) = y \in \mathbb{R} \}\subset \Omega
$$
that is, $Y = y$ is actually a subset of our sample space and to stress this it is also denoted by $\{Y = y\}$. It is the space of all outcomes that our random variable maps to $y\in \mathbb{R}$.  In this notation, we assume $y\in \mathbb{R}$ to be fixed. We call $Y$ a random variable (which is actually a function) and we call $y$ a realization of $Y$ (meaning that $y$ is a particular value that the function $Y$ can assume).
To give an example we look at an experiment: rolling two dice and looking at the sum of values. In this case we may consider $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \times \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $Y(i,j) = i+j$ (you may check that this is a random variable).
In this case, saying $Y = 3$ (where $y=3$) corresponds to the set $$\{Y = 3\} = \{(i,j) \in \Omega \: : \: Y(i,j) = 3\} = \{ (i,j) \in \Omega \: : \: i+j = 3\} = \{(1,2), (2,1) \}$$
Notice that $Y=y$ does not specify some particular value of $Y$ but it specifies a subset of our sample space.
I hope this helps!
